# Getting the body of a question, or answer, through API

Tags: support, api

You can fetch a question by providing its id, via SO's API. See [this page](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/questions-by-ids), for more information.

However, the returned JSON, has no body containing the actual text of the question. Is it by design? Am I following a wrong path?

Answer (score 26):

`body=true` doesn't seem to work with the 2.1 API, but you can add `filter=withbody`:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/113204?site=meta.stackoverflow&filter=withbody

Or you create a [custom filter](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) that includes the body.

Comment: there is some discussion about your lack of user name - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195798/cannot-user-reply-to-clever-users-with-unicode-user-names-on-safari#195798

Comment: The first link does not work, it returns zero. Can I have a filter=withlink? This seems also good for comments. How does the customer filter work regarding withbody? At the bottom: `withbody, which is default plus the *.body fields`

Comment: I look for the body AND title. How would this work? Is there a withtitle?

Answer (score 10):

Recently, the Stack Exchange API has been upgraded to v2.2. So the earlier answers cannot work now. The query should be:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/43225521?&site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody

Related documents can be seen in the [page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids).

Comment: I look for the body AND link of **Comments**. How would this work?

Answer (score 7):

[image: Another parameter is needed...]

Comment: OMG, stupid me. How on earth I didn't see that. :(. Thanks @Bobby.

Comment: For whatever reason, I rejoice in the clarity and rigor of your image-only answer.

Comment: this is no longer correct. `body` is no longer listed as a parameter