# Cannot @ reply to users with usernames composed of non-visible unicode characters

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-accounts

We have a potentially clever user in the ways of unicode or javascript user name validation *(and certainly very knowledgable in general)* that managed to get what is effectively a null user name from the normal process to change user names in their account management tools:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/3936/

The [validation for Zero Width Joiners and other odd Unicode characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10519/165931) might need tweaking or implementing on user page edit validation.

Asking users one by one to change their name won't scale well if this is a bug in the validation code.

Here's what I see in comments about the lack of a linkable name:

[image: rendering of a user with a hidden name]

Tearing into the rendering of the page, what would look like this for a user with a more traditional name:

```
        <div class="user-details">
            <a href="/users/5472/bmike">bmike</a><br>
            <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score" dir="ptr">42</span>
        </div>
```

The user with the brief unicode name:

```
        <div class="user-details">
            <a href="/users/3936/">͏͏͏</a><br>
            <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score" dir="ptr">42</span>
        </div>
```

Is this a bug in the user entry validation checks or the rendering of this particular name as it sits in the database or do I need to be equally clever to @ message users with names like this one on the site?

Comment: I don't see his name either, on Chrome or Internet Explorer

Comment: Nor in FF.  He's a ghost!

Comment: possible solution, not sure though, you could try hitting him up using his user number like @user3936

Comment: If only we had more ghosts like this user. I'll edit out the safari info since this looks to be [tag:status-repro] at this point.

Comment: perhaps we shouldn't contact users with silly unusable names to discourage the practice

Comment: I saw this in Chrome, and mobile Chrome (iOS). Odd.

Comment: Not sure whether good or bad, but I notice three square brackets in Opera.

Comment: It's some unicode characters. No bug here, just someone who think it's funny.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd If someone wants to upload the unicode used and re-tag it unicode that would be great. Again, I wanted the developers to be aware of it and it's not a huge hassle as long as it's not breaking things elsewhere.

Comment: @bmike unicode is allowed in display names from the very beginning as far as I know, it can't break anything as it's just text. Those users will still get notifications on answers made on their questions and comments made on their posts, the lack of `@`-reply is pretty minor and I'm sure most of them are well aware of that.

Comment: Probably zero-width spaces

Comment: @bmike They're Combining Grapheme Joiners (U+034F). Isn't Unicode grand?

Comment: @͏͏͏ Odd that I see ghost characters here but not on Ask Different...

Comment: Also, @ replies appear to work if you tab to accept the default match and no two people chose the same unicode display name for the thread in question.

Comment: @bmike Not seeing any characters here. Those joiners aren't supposed to have a visible glyph so that'd be a bit peculiar.

Comment: It's quite peculiar looking… http://cl.ly/RCTj

Comment: Unicode. You can do so many stupid things with it.‮siht ekiL –‭

Comment: Honestly, I would change their username because I see this as circumventing validation.

Comment: Do people try to use their invisible ink on stackexchange too? O.o

Comment: I see ghost characters as well. Not on his profile or usercard, but in the comment field. It's a combining character so iirc if there's stuff around it which it can't combine with, it ghosts. Alternatively, the fonts used in the comment signature contain the ghost character, while the fonts for the usercard/profile don't

Comment: They’re specifically trying to be clever because they also used a blank (solid, transparent) avatar. It seems inane and usernames should probably be run through a filter to prevent exploits.

Answer (score 6):

Since the cat is out of the bag so to speak, here's the remedy I would propose - extend the validation that should be in place for other input to the user editable fields:

[Comments, questions and answers don't trim Unicode U200B when counting characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10519/comments-questions-and-answers-dont-trim-unicode-u200b-when-counting-character?lq=1)

I don't see a reason to suppress unicode in general, just have a sanity check that a name isn't exclusively oddball characters that break other functionality (like a working @ reply).

Additionally, you could add a second check to ensure that no `div class="user-details"` gets a null href rendered for the target of the user link. So

```
    <div class="user-details">
        <a href="/users/3936/">͏͏͏</a><br>
        <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score" dir="ptr">42</span>
    </div>
```

would change to

```
    <div class="user-details">
        <a href="/users/3936/">͏͏͏reply to the author of this post</a><br>
        <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score" dir="ptr">42</span>
    </div>
```

If the text placed in for "reply to the author of this post" is functional, who cares what name is rendered elsewhere. This second code change might be good to have down the road in case the validator becomes broken for certain characters or a regression test doesn't catch other oddities from unicode.

Comment: If we don’t know to put it in the validator, how are we going to know to put it in the comment filter?

Comment: @minitech, then why not just detect and block certain characters from usernames upon creation/modification?

Comment: Curious.  Can someone put the moderator diamond after their name? Like MyName ♦ ?

Comment: @tgm1024 I believe thee are some rudimentary checks, but I also don’t doubt if someone manages to find some bug or Unicode character that’s not caught, they would be flagged quite promptly and asked to reconsider their decision to attempt that.