# Why can't I see the profile of this user?

Tags: discussion

I saw something terrible in [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) site that, i can't able to view the profile of a particular user who posted [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152746/56901) answer.

[image]

Did the user got deleted?

Comment: I can view the profile

Comment: @juergend: but it is hard because the username is 'funny'.

Comment: Related, possible dupe: [Cannot @ reply to users with usernames composed of non-visible unicode characters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195798)

Comment: Which is, in fact, about the very same user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a deleted user has a gray background as usercard and no reputation and no badges. The user has 3 Unicode characters as username, which is hard to click on:

[image: Unicode username]

By zooming in I could find where I had to click, and that way I found the link to his profile: https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/10053/%D8%98%D8%98%D8%98

Comment: is that SE allows a null username?

Comment: @AvinashRaj It is not null, it is a Unicode character.

Comment: @ProgramFOX: it is 3 unicode characters; three times [U+0618 ARABIC SMALL FATHA](http://codepoints.net/U+0618).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, answer updated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be less a problem if the reputation itself was clickable? Additionally his avatar (though transparent) is still there and clickable as well.

Comment: @plannapus Yes, that would solve the problem.