# Stack Exchange API - Get answer's markdown

Tags: support, markdown, api

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113204/getting-the-body-of-a-question-or-answer-through-api) shows that one can get an answer body for a Stack Exchange question. However, I'm trying to see if it's possible to get the original markdown version of the answer, not one that's been converted to HTML.

Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the field `body_markdown` returns the post body *in MarkDown*.

[Live Example](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=264298&filter=!GeEyUcJFJeD0Q&site=meta&run=true): so **meta**.

Comment: This is the most meta-meta-meta-meta-ness ever. Perfect and thanks!!

Comment: do you know why this request requires an access token? I'm not making any changes....

Comment: It shouldn't, and (for me) it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry - learning here. I edited the filter and chose an option that requires elevated access. All good now. Thanks!!!